# Focus Highlighting issue with Combo box and Radio Button with Enter Key pressed event

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, focus

I have been working on `PyQt` focus method for different widgets whenever <kbd>Enter</kbd> key pressed instead of conventional <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Furthermore, I am able to set focus to the widget which I intended upon <kbd>Enter</kbd> key event. However, whenever the focus is on `QComboBox` or `QRadioButton`, these two widgets don't seems to highlight like `QLineEdit` or `QPushButton` widgets.

I know that I have to set focus policy to `StrongFocus` and I have tried that and several other methods but unable to fix this issue.
Moreover, this behaviour is working perfectly fine and combo box or radio button seems to highlight as well with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Please find below my tried code until now and also snapshot for the actual results.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class Combo_and_Radio_Focus(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # setting title
        self.setWindowTitle("Combo Box Focus Test")

        # setting geometry
        self.setGeometry(600, 200, 650, 400)

        # Some widgets for testing
        self.le1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.le1.setFixedSize(100, 25)

        self.le2 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.le2.setFixedSize(100, 25)

        self.cbo1 = QComboBox(self)
        self.cbo1.setFixedSize(100, 25)
        self.cbo1.setStyleSheet('QComboBox {background-color: white;}')
        self.cbo1.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.cbo1.addItems(["", "Item1", "Item2", "Item3"])

        self.cbo2 = QComboBox(self)
        self.cbo2.setFixedSize(100, 25)
        self.cbo2.setStyleSheet('QComboBox {background-color: white;}')
        self.cbo2.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.cbo2.addItems(["", "Item1", "Item2", "Item3"])

        self.RB1 = QRadioButton("1")
        self.RB1.setChecked(True)
        self.RB1.setFixedSize(100, 20)
        self.RB1.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)

        self.RB2 = QRadioButton("2")
        self.RB2.setFixedSize(100, 20)
        self.RB2.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)

        self.vbl = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.le1)
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.le2)
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.cbo1)
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.cbo2)
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.RB1)
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.RB2)

        self.setLayout(self.vbl)

        # showing all the widgets
        self.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, qKeyEvent):
        if int(qKeyEvent.modifiers()) == QtCore.Qt.AltModifier:
            qKeyEvent.ignore()
            return

        if qKeyEvent.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return or qKeyEvent.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter:
            QWidget.focusNextChild(self)

        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(qKeyEvent)


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
App.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))

# create the instance of our Window
combo_and_Radio_Focus = Combo_and_Radio_Focus()

# start the app
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

LineEdit1_Highlighted Below

[image: LineEdit_Highlight]

ComboBox1_Dont_Highlight Below

[image: ComboBox_Dont_Highlight]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the <kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed to make the focus change then the application sets the `Qt.WA_KeyboardFocusChange` attribute in the window and that is used by the QStyle to make the border painting but since this is not the case then that attribute has to be set directly:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, qKeyEvent):
    if qKeyEvent.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.AltModifier:
        qKeyEvent.ignore()
    elif qKeyEvent.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter):
        self.focusNextChild()
        self.window().setAttribute(Qt.WA_KeyboardFocusChange)
    else:
        super().keyPressEvent(qKeyEvent)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance, didn't know this detail and instead tried lots of other things. Thank again :)